# Delete line from textarea post result using Regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to delete a line from textarea post result, starting with "To"
My try:

```
$var = 'Date: __date\n"."Mime-Version: 1.0\nFrom: __From \nTo: __To\nSubject: __Subject         \nReply-To: __Reply-To\nX-Job: __X-Job';

$text = preg_replace("/To(.*)$\n/s","",$var);
```

but it did not work.

i want this output

```
Date: __date\n"."Mime-Version: 1.0\nFrom: __From \nSubject: __Subject         \nReply-To: __Reply-To\nX-Job: __X-Job'
```

Edit: 
The last solution i used, which take into consideration that the input is from textarea

```
        $text = preg_replace("/To.*?Subject:/s","Subject:",$var);
```

Comment: Can we assume that you're using double quotes to enclose the string? Single quotes will not work in the same manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `/m` modifier so that the `^` matches the start of each line, and then use this expression:

```
$text = preg_replace("/^To:.*/m", "", $var);
```

I'm not using the `/s` modifier, because that would cause `.` to match newlines as well, and that's not what you want here.

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/C1ltu3)

Btw, according to the specification, MIME headers may span multiple lines; I'm ignoring that in this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First solution, without using `\n` and any *modifier*, that first the problem description:

```
$text = preg_replace("/To.*?Subject:/","Subject:",$var);
```

This is a more generic version that uses the ending `\n` as a separator.

```
$text = preg_replace("/\bTo:.*?\n/", "", $var, 1);
```

- `\b` to mark the beginning of a word
- `.*?` having `?` for *not greedy*, meaning matching stop when `\n` is met
- the final `1` tells `preg_replace` to replace only one (the first) occurence
  (I forgot it initially, and default is all - *PHP* is not *Perl*..)

Note: in php `$var = ' x\n y\n';` will not expand the `\n` as CR, since the single quotes `'` are used. Double quotes have to be used: `$var = " x\n y\n";` to get `x` and `y` on separate lines.

--

(actually, to be more precise, `/\bTo:.*\n/` would work also, since the `s` modifier is not used the `.*` doesn't match the `\n`. Having the `s` modifier `.` matches the `\n` and the `?` is necessary: `/\bTo:.*?\n/s`. But it is more clear to use it with the `?` anyway, and better not to forget this useful option!)

Comment: like that, it delete all words after To, i want this output
Date: __date\n"."Mime-Version: 1.0\nFrom: __From \nSubject: __Subject         \nReply-To: __Reply-To\nX-Job: __X-Job'

Comment: It works only this isolated case, if Subject doesn't follow To it won't work as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is not the perfect solution, but it can do the work :)

Comment: Updated the answer for a more generic solution.

Comment: @Jack I have already looked to your answer , but it does not work, you can try http://codepad.org/9pcOCPMj
@ ring0 the second solution does not work http://codepad.org/H529ziyF

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [explode](https://www.php.net/explode):

```
$var = 'Date: __date\n"."Mime-Version: 1.0\nFrom: __From \nTo: __To\nSubject: __Subject         \nReply-To: __Reply-To\nX-Job: __X-Job';
$arr = explode('\n', $var);
```

Now unset which key you want